# What does it mean to assign a conductor?

Tags: cables, conductors, sata

I am reading about SATA power [here](https://itstillworks.com/ata-hard-drive-vs-sata-5481231.html).

They say the following:

> The power cables for the SATA interface are of similar construction as
> the signal cables, but have 15 conductors. They supply power to the
> hard or optical drive at the voltage levels of 3.3, 5 and 12 volts.
> Each voltage has three conductors assigned to it because the wires and
> connecting pins are too small to be able to handle the full current
> required by the drive. Three ground wires between each two voltage
> levels make up the balance of the 15 conductors. The SATA power cables
> connect the computer power supply to the drives.

I understand a conductor is a metal and that you can mix different metals in the wire to achieve different electrical properties but it is unclear to me what they mean by assigning a conductor. Does this mean that three are three different metals in each wire?

Comment: No, just that there are three wires per power supply voltage. Nothing fancy.

Comment: No, three conductor **pins** on the connector, that connect to one single wire.

Comment: "Assigned" is a fancy word for saying "choose that thing to do something". As in pointing to something and saying I decide it will be this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Each voltage had three conductors assigned to it" means the same as "for each voltage, the designers chose three pins on the connector to carry that voltage from the power supply to the disk". Three pins were used to carry 3.3 V, another three were used for 5 V, another three for 12 V, and the remaining six were used for ground.

The wires are likely identical aside from insulation color. The connector pins *are* slightly different in shape/size - the ground pins are longer so they make contact first.